# Error 403 google spreadsheets gspread when open in console

Tags: python, api, airflow, gspread

I'm trying to repeat the guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vISRn5qFrkM) - generated **client_secrets.json**, put it in the ***DAGs folder*** (because then I will run the script from airflow)
But despite the client secret-still gives the error ***403-not enough rights*** , how can I fix it?

```
 import gspread
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    import pprint
    
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json',scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    
    sheet = client.open('Data base').sheet4
    
    result = sheet.get_all_records()
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

self solved - apparently when you use the file name it refers to the disk API to find this file
therefore, you must also log in to drive. to do this, you need to add it to the scope

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pprint

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json',scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)


sheet = client.open('Data base').worksheet("Sum Data")


result = sheet.get_all_records()
print(result)
```